# Datasource is missing when editing role permissions on Superset

Tags: apache-superset

On Superset (Airbnb/Apache) I'm trying to set the permission of the role "Financeiro" to the datasource "aleteia_contas" but it's missing. Superset version 0.17.1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this still an issue? Have you tried the latest version of Superset?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've tried on version "0.25.6" too. I think it's because the database structure is awful.